# ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> error with makeglossaries

Tags: errors, debugging

I'm getting these two errors after compile with makeglossary. If I compile my .tex file with `PDFLatex->makeindex->PDFLatex` runs without problem but if I change this command series to `PDFLatex->makeglossaries->makeindex->PDFLatex` throws me back the following errors:

```
[8] (build/TesisDeGrado.gls) [9]
(build/TesisDeGrado.acr
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
m
l.5 ...\glsnumberformat{3\delimN 4}}}\glsgroupskip
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
```

[image]

This is my code:

TesisDeGrado.tex

```
\documentclass[11 pt, letterpaper, twoside, openright]{icontec}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{LISTA DE SÍMBOLOS}


%Acronym definitions
\newacronym{ese}{ESE}{Empresa Social del Estado}
\newacronym{huem}{HUEM}{Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz}
% nomenclature:

\newglossaryentry{angelsperarea}{
  name = $a$ ,
  description = The number of angels per unit area,
}
\newglossaryentry{numofangels}{
  name = $N$ ,
  description = The number of angels per needle point
}
\newglossaryentry{areaofneedle}{
  name = $A$ ,
  description = The area of the needle point
}

\makeglossaries

\backgroundsetup{
contents={\includegraphics[natwidth=1300,natheight=1700]{escudounipamplona.png}},
angle=0, 
scale=0.45, 
color=black, 
opacity=0.1
}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\BgThispage
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{
\huge\textbf{Diseño de políticas mantenimiento basadas en ingeniería de confiabilidad y propuesta para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta}  

\vspace{5cm}
{\normalsize \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar\\

\vspace{5cm}
Programa de ingeniería mecatrónica \\
Departamento de ingeniería mecánica, mecatrónica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\BgThispage
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{
\Large\textbf{Diseño de políticas mantenimiento basadas en ingeniería de confiabilidad y propuesta para la mejora operacional a equipos electromecánicos del Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz de Cúcuta} 

\vspace{2cm}
{\small \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar \\
{\small \textit{Codigo: 1116249797}} \\
{\small\textit{Correo electronico: judabo@unipamplona.edu.co}} 

\vspace{1cm}
{\small \textit{Practica laboral para optar al titulo de}}\\
Ingeniero mecatrónico

\vspace{1cm}
{\small\textit{Director}} \\
MSc. Oscar Manuel Duque Suarez\\
{\small\textit{Master en controles industriales}} \\
{\small \textit{Correo electrónico: omduque@unipamplona.edu.co}} 

\vspace{0.5cm}
{\small\textit{Supervisor}} \\
Ing. Rafael Antonio Sepulveda Ayala \\
{\small \textit{Coord. de mantenimiento, Hospital Universitario Erasmo Meoz}} 

\vspace{2cm}
Programa de ingeniería mecatrónica \\
Departamento de ingeniería mecánica, mecatrónica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\hfill
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{c}
    Nota de aceptación:\\
    \hspace*{0.5\textwidth}\\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \vspace{3cm}\\\hline
    Firma del presidente del jurado
    \vspace{3cm}\\\hline
    Firma del jurado\\
    \vspace{3cm}\\\hline
    Firma del jurado
 \end{tabularx}

\vspace{4cm}
Ciudad y fecha (día, mes, año)
\newpage
\begin{flushright}
\null\vspace{\stretch{1}}
Aquí va la dedicatoria, la lista es larga...
\vspace{\stretch{2}}\null
\end{flushright}
\newpage

\begin{flushright}
\null\vspace{\stretch{1}}
Agradecimientos.
\vspace{\stretch{2}}\null
\end{flushright}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\printglossary[title=LISTA DE SIMBOLOS]
\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=LISTA DE ACRONIMOS]
\mainmatter
\include{intro}
\include{Chap1}


\end{document}
```

[icontec.cls and icontec.sty files](https://db.tt/ewmU4fYw)

**EDIT** I found the problem. The error is generated by the icontec.cls but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Please try to make your example a bit more minimal. You can learn how to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) by following the link.

Comment: But I'd guess that you probably want some curly brackets there e.g. `{$a$}` and `{The area of the needle point}`. Also, at least one column in your column spec for `tabularx` must be `X`.